# Reload Backbone.View after Ajax request.How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, backbone-views

i've got ajax request in `Backbone.View` to `change` collection:

```
change: function(model, options){
me = this;
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'getShortcode',
        shortcode: model.attributes.shortcode
    },
    success: function (data) {
       me.$el.find('section:eq(' + model.collection.indexOf(model) + ')').replaceWith(data);
       me.add( model, model.collection );
    }
});
}
```

But after ajax request, my another `Backbone.View` (which call this ajax via triggers) don't work again, how a can "reload" my another `Backbone.View` after ajax, to force triggers call ajax again? thx!

Comment: "to change model" using `$.ajax`? Why don't you use the `model`'s methods? Also your question is too broad. Backbone(and JavaScript in general) is _event_-based. You should listen to events and control your application flow accordingly.

Comment: @Vohuman sorry, what do you mean, don't understand

Comment: @Vohuman sorry again, i'm change collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a Backbone.Model . If your model is already a Backbone.Model, just use `model.set( anObjectWithTheChanges )` and that will trigger a `change` event in the model.

Then, just add some code in your view's `initialize` function to listen to the changes in your model. Something like:

```
this.listenTo( this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

where `render` is the method in your view in charge of the refresh.

Comment: i'm trying to add `this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.change);` in my `Backbone.View` with triggers, and see error: `Cannot read property '_listenerId' of undefined`

Comment: It appears that the collection might not be defined by the time you try to listen to its events. Have you defined this.collection in the view's `initialize` method **before** calling `this.listenTo`?